# What's the Total error mean in pybrain during training?

Tags: python, pybrain

Here is my code:

```
from pybrain.structure import *
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
fnn = FeedForwardNetwork()
inLayer = LinearLayer(2, name='inLayer')
hiddenLayer = SigmoidLayer(7, name='hiddenLayer0')
outLayer = LinearLayer(1, name='outLayer')
fnn.addInputModule(inLayer)
fnn.addModule(hiddenLayer)
fnn.addOutputModule(outLayer)
in_to_hidden = FullConnection(inLayer, hiddenLayer)
hidden_to_out = FullConnection(hiddenLayer, outLayer)
fnn.addConnection(in_to_hidden)
fnn.addConnection(hidden_to_out)
fnn.sortModules()
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
DS = SupervisedDataSet(2,1)
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        DS.addSample([i,j], [i*j])
X = DS['input']
Y = DS['target']
dataTrain, dataTest = DS.splitWithProportion(0.8)
xTrain, yTrain = dataTrain['input'], dataTrain['target']
xTest, yTest = dataTest['input'], dataTest['target']
trainer = BackpropTrainer(fnn, dataTrain, verbose = True, learningrate=0.01)
trainer.trainUntilConvergence(maxEpochs=1000)
```

When i run this code,I got a `total error` for every epoch.I cant understand it.What does `total error` mean? And it look like a little large.

Here are some `total error` of those :

```
Total error:  2421098.90561
Total error:  2421079.7975
Total error:  2419968.22232
Total error:  2423552.04539
Total error:  2423015.61675
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program logic is flawed. You might be misunderstanding the whole concept of training with neural networks and what an epoch is. This following lines are your problem:

```
for i in range(100):
    trainer.trainEpochs( 1 )
```

You are not training a network 100 epochs, instead, in each iteration you are training your network using one epoch and then you are stopping and starting from scratch again.

You don't need that for loop. Remove the for loop and just specify that you want 100 epochs:

```
trainer.trainEpochs(100)
```

You can think of an epoch as one iteration in your learning process.

The "total error" you are showing tells me that there is something wrong with how you have setup the network. With the data you are using and a three layer network, the error should continuously decrease until it converges to some small value.

What is this "total error"? Every time you train the network, the network is learning how to transform the inputs into the outputs you provide. The "total error" is the average reconstruction error: the intended output minus the actual obtained output (squared), and the average of these for all inputs.

Comment: yes,you correct me! But it's not the point. Do you think it's the point of my dataset with `ClassificationDataSet`.What will result the learning can't be better? Is that right？

Comment: My dataset `for i in range(20):
 for j in range(20):
  alldata.addSample([i,j], [i*j])`

Comment: I tried to answer as stated in your question. If your questions was different, could you edit your original question with the actual question?